# Restricting access to a Rails Engine's routes...constraints not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-engines

I've got a Rails Engine in my app. Here's its hook into my `routes.rb` file:

```
Mercury::Engine.routes
```

I'm trying to restrict access to the URLs provided by the engine so I tried using constraints:

```
class EditorRestrictor
  def self.matches?(request)
    false
  end
end

constraints EditorRestrictor do
  Mercury::Engine.routes
end
```

But the engine's routes are still accessible. I restarted my app just in case but it didn't matter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd mount routes for your engines like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    mount Mercury::Engine => '/mercury'

    # If you wanted routes mounted on root
    # mount Mercury::Engine => '/'    
end
```

So if you want to add constraints, you could say:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    mount Mercury::Engine => '/mercury', constraints: {}
end
```